# Confused about Identical Icon files in Windows Phone 8 apps

Tags: c#, .net, language-agnostic, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

Why are there 2 of the same icons in Visual Studio?

If you type:

`<shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="new document" IconUri="" />` and then open the Properties pane and open up the ComboBox for the ApplicationBarIconButton element, you'll notice that this comb box has an `add` button and a `new` button icon. And when you look at both icons - they're the same.

But why?

I know that, in context, both new, and add, can have different meanings/perform different actions:

E.g. New could create a new document, while `add` could attach something/add something to the currently-open document.

But then if that's the reasoning - then both icons should be different as this could potentially lead to confusion because the default state of the Application bar icon's is set such that the text of the icon is not visible unless you tap on the `...` to the bottom right of the screen. So if I had both an add and a new button in the ApplicationBar menu, while in default state, this could be very confusing and will force the user to open the menu just to see which button is which. Which goes against the purpose of hiding the menubar text in the first place, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't see `add` and `new` buttons. Which version of Visual Studio are you using? Can you include a screenshot

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone.

Comment: I still don't see two buttons.

Comment: They're there. Not next to each other but scroll down the list and you should see a new button too

Comment: It would help to see a screenshot of what you are seeing.

Comment: I can't add a screenshot without taking multiple screenshots and editing them because the "new" option is way too down the list from the "add" option - which is up the top.

Answer (score 0):

I try not to spend a whole lot of valuable development time trying to figure all the reasons as to why Microsoft decides to implement one default image over another in a development environment.  It is my responsibility as the developer to choose exactly how I want the program to look and feel.

There are a lot of standard icons to choose from that come bundled with the SDK.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Icons\

Additionally, here is how someone can create their own custom Application Bar.  One alternative button icon approach is to continuing using the standard `add.png` image for the `New` button and use the `check.png` image for the `Add` button if it is really necessary to have both types of actions on the same Application Bar.

```
public partial class MyPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BuildApplicationBar();
    }

    private void BuildApplicationBar()
    {
        // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.    
        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

        ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Default;
        ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
        ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1.0;
        ApplicationBar.IsMenuEnabled = true;

        // Create new buttons
        ApplicationBarIconButton AppBarAddButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/check.png", UriKind.Relative));
        AppBarAddButton.Text = "Add";
        AppBarAddButton.Click += new EventHandler(AppBarAddButton_Click);
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(AppBarAddButton);

        ApplicationBarIconButton AppBarNewButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/add.png", UriKind.Relative));
        AppBarNewButton.Text = "New";
        AppBarNewButton.Click += new EventHandler(AppBarNewButton_Click);
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(AppBarNewButton);
    }

    private async void AppBarAddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO: Do something for the add click action
    }

    private async void AppBarNewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO: Do something for the new click action
    }
}
```